# Ruby on rails. Add facebook.com/ to URL if not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

my users have the option to add their website, facebook and twitter URL's to their profile.

I want to let them enter either the full URL (http://www.facebook.com/`USERNAME`) or part of the URL Eg. www.facebook.com/`USERNAME` or just `USERNAME`, and then have the https://facebook.com/ added automatically if needed. I want the http:// as then the entered URL will link directly to their website/facebook etc.

For the website URL I have:

```
before_validation :add_url_protocol

def add_url_protocol
  if self.website && !url_protocol_present?
    self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
  end
end

def url_protocol_present?
  self.website[/\Ahttp:\/\//] || self.website[/\Ahttps:\/\//]
end
```

There is then further regex validation. 
This works fine.

The thing is I don't have much of an idea about regex and I am unsure on how to add the facebook.com/ part to this `before_validation` code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

```
def add_url_protocol
  if self.website && !url_protocol_present?
    self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
  end
  if self.facebook && !url_facebook_present?
    self.facebook = "http://facebook.com/#{self.facebook}"
  end
end
```

This almost works. If a user inputs `USERNAME` then the output is good. If the user inputs www.facebook.com/`USERNAME` then the ouput becomes http://facebook.com/www.facebook.com/`USERNAME`

Comment: whay did you confused with: `self.website = "http://facebook.com/#{self.username}"`?

Comment: Almost, but if the user types www.facebook.com/USERNAME , the ouput becomes http://www.facebook.com/www.facebook.com/USERNAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to collect user input in a form model, you can roll your own with by including `ActiveModel::Model` or use something like [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform). 
The easiest thing you can do is simply treat their input as a string containing their facebook username separated by "/" so whatever the string they enter you can get the username by

```
"https://www.facebook.com/their.username".split('/')[-1] # 'their.username'
"www.facebook.com/their.username".split('/')[-1] # 'their.username'

"their.username".split('/')[-1] # 'their.username'
```

Simply declare a username attribute in your form model and overwrite the setter to extract the facebook username. Then only save the facebook username in your database, and write a method such as

```
def facebook_profile_url
   "www.facebook.com/#{fb_username}"
end
```

No need to persist the redundant facebook url part.

Comment: .split('/')[-1] seems to be working well. I have a regex validation for the inputs so before that, I create a variable fb_username = self.facebook..split('/')[-1] . After validation I put the full URL in front of the new variable and save it as self.facebook

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
match = /^(https?:\/\/)?((www\.)?facebook\.com)?(.*)/.match(self.website)
self.website = match[1] || 'http://'
self.website << match[2] || 'facebook.com'
self.website << match[3]
```

You can create capture groups by using parentheses.  The ? means that group or char before it is optional (so I was able to condense your protocol search)

You may need to check my indexes into the match array...

Sorry this is untested as it is from a phone...